# Django csrf fails after logout login new user

Tags: django, django-csrf

Even if I understand the problem, I'm not sure how to solve this. I have a django powered api that has an endpoint that lets the user change the email. If the logged user A enters a **already existing** email, it checks if the logged user A entered a password that corresponds to the already existing user B object (i.e he owns another, older account). If that is the case, I have to logout the actual user A and login again the already existing B account.

```
...
if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
    # If the email already belongs to another account
    user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        # The user is the owner of the existing account, he has the password
        # Get already existing client object
        client_existing_user_obj = Client.objects.get(user=user)

        # get clients actual cart
        actual_cart = client.cart
        # update existing clients cart with newly created cart
        client_existing_user_obj.cart = actual_cart

        # logout user with the old email, login already existing user
        logout(request)
        login(request, user)

        ...
```

The endpoint works correctly, it returns 200. However, the next post & put requests answer 403 -  "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."

How can I solve this? Any advice will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django [rotates the CSRF token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#why-might-a-user-encounter-a-csrf-validation-failure-after-logging-in) when a user logs in. This is a security measure.

You'll have to refresh the token after login (e.g by refreshing the page) before you submit more POST/PUT requests.